# Human readable date format in android java

Tags: human-readable

For Example

**Date to convert** is 2020-05-10 01:00:00
**Current Date** is 2020-05-20 01:00:00

It should show **10 days ago**

I'm using Calendar class

`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();`

Comment: Don't use `Calendar`, use `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for this, it is now available to lower API versions in Android due to [Android API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create the datetime ten days ago
    LocalDateTime tenDaysBefore = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 10, 1, 0, 0);
    // create the one that is used as "today"
    LocalDateTime current = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 20, 1, 0, 0);
    // calculate the period between them (this only considers the date part)
    Period period = Period.between(tenDaysBefore.toLocalDate(), current.toLocalDate());
    // define a formatter for human readable output
    DateTimeFormatter outputDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd 'of' MMMM uuuu",
                                                                Locale.ENGLISH);
    // and output a meaningful sentence
    System.out.println(tenDaysBefore.format(outputDtf) + " was (approximately) "
                        + period.getDays() + " days ago assuming "
                        + current.format(outputDtf) + " is \"today\"");
}
```

This outputs

```
Sunday, 10 of May 2020 was (approximately) 10 days ago assuming Wednesday, 20 of May 2020 is "today"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) - 10);
System.out.println(DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", calendar).toString());
```

I'm using it. It will automatically remove 10 days from the current date.

Output: `I/System.out: 2020-09-07 12:51:50`